# How to change ApexCharts label size, font and position in the pie chart

Tags: javascript, charts, apexcharts

I'm using ApexCharts.js to add pie chart component on my page.
And I need to change the label size, font and position to bottom.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eligrey-classlist-js-polyfill@1.2.20171210/classList.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/findindex_polyfill_mdn"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<body>
  <div id="pieChart"></div>
  <script>
    var options = {
      series: [10, 20, 30, 50],
      chart: {
        height: 480,
        type: 'pie',
      },
      labels: ["series_1", "series_2", "series_3", "series_4"],
      colors: ["#ff0000", "#c758d0", "#d6d6d6", "#007ed6"],
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 480,
        options: {
          chart: {
            width: 200
          },
          legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
          }
        }
      }]
    };
    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#pieChart"), options);
    chart.render();
  </script>
</body>
```

Finally, I want my chart to look like this
[image]

Do you have any idea how to modify the code so to get the same result as it is on the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added your labels to the bottom.
You can edit the spacing by modifying:

```
itemMargin: {
  horizontal: 5,
  vertical: 0
},
```

Docs can be found here: https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/legend/

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eligrey-classlist-js-polyfill@1.2.20171210/classList.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/findindex_polyfill_mdn"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<body>
  <div id="pieChart"></div>
  <script>
    var options = {
      series: [10, 20, 30, 50],
      chart: {
        height: 480,
        type: 'pie',
      },
      labels: ["series_1", "series_2", "series_3", "series_4"],
      colors: ["#ff0000", "#c758d0", "#d6d6d6", "#007ed6"],
      legend: {
        show: true,
        showForSingleSeries: false,
        showForNullSeries: true,
        showForZeroSeries: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        horizontalAlign: 'center', 
        fontSize: '18px',
        fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial',
        fontWeight: 400,
        itemMargin: {
            horizontal: 15,
            vertical: 0
        },
      },
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 480,
        options: {
          chart: {
            width: 200
          },
        }
      }]
    };
    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#pieChart"), options);
    chart.render();
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's what I was looking for. I did not know Legend has to be configured but not label. One more question if you are aware, Can I activate the download buttons on a pie chart? I can see it on the bar, column, area... charts but can't find it on the pie chart. Is there any way to activate it?

Comment: You mean export to image?

Comment: Yes, for example "column charts" has an option to export SVG, PNG and CSV

Comment: I found it, 'toolbar: {show: true}' should be added inside the chart block

Answer (score 3):

The display of the labels are actually called "legend" and all possible options are documented on this [page](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/legend/).

In your case, "legend" was nested too deep, it needs to be on the first level. To change the font size and font weight, you need to add the corresponding options "fontSize" and "fontWeight".

Here is a working example:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eligrey-classlist-js-polyfill@1.2.20171210/classList.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/findindex_polyfill_mdn"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<body>
  <div id="pieChart"></div>
  <script>
    var options = {
      series: [10, 20, 30, 50],
      chart: {
        height: 480,
        type: 'pie',
      },
      labels: ["series_1", "series_2", "series_3", "series_4"],
      legend: {
          position: 'bottom',
          fontSize: '24px',
          fontWeight: 600,
      },
      colors: ["#ff0000", "#c758d0", "#d6d6d6", "#007ed6"],
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 480,
        options: {
          chart: {
            width: 200
          },
        }
      }]
    };
    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#pieChart"), options);
    chart.render();
  </script>
</body>
```